# How do you unbind a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcuts

I'm wondering how I can unbind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up desktop/minimize windows. Whenever I jump and crouch in an FPS it minimizes the game. I searched and found people saying to edit `lubuntu-rc.xml` but I couldn't find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> bindings in there (I might have missed it, could be wrong)

Btw, this only happens when I hold them both down for a second, as opposed to alt tab when I press alt+tab at the same time it changes windows instantly. Also this only happens in the FPS game which is weird. I just switched to Lubuntu from Ubuntu so I don't know why this suddenly started happening it didn't do this on Ubuntu

EDIT; no need to answer, I solved it. I'm not sure why this only happened in game but in case someone has this same problem I went to <kbd>Menu</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard Input Methods</kbd> and where it says <kbd>Next Input Method</kbd> I deleted the bind to control space.

Comment: You can answer your own question, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

As the user seems to have been off-line for quite a while, answering the question for it, so that other people will not try to solve "unsolved" questions:

In Lubuntu, go to <kbd>Menu</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard Input Methods</kbd> and where it says `Next Input Method` delete the bind to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.